# Combining two identically-structured tables where one has priority, and also excluding by field value

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have two tables, like this:

```
t_Normal
----------------------------------------------
FieldKey   | FieldLabel      | FieldValue
----------------------------------------------
greet_hw   | Hello, world!   | HELLOWORLD
----------------------------------------------
greet_ws   | What's shakin?  | WHATISSHAKING
----------------------------------------------
greet_hh   | How's it hangin?| HOWDOESITHANG
----------------------------------------------

t_Override
------------------------------------------------------------
FieldKey   | FieldLabel      | FieldValue    | FieldStatus
------------------------------------------------------------
greet_ws   | What's shakin?  | WHATISSHAKING | Retired
------------------------------------------------------------
greet_s    | Sup!?!??        | SUPELEVEN     | Active
------------------------------------------------------------
greet_hh   | How swings it?  | HOWDOESITHANG | Active
------------------------------------------------------------
```

Can I join them in a view to get this:

```
v_FieldMaster
---------------------------------------------
FieldKey   | FieldLabel      | FieldValue    
---------------------------------------------
greet_hw   | Hello, world!   | HELLOWORLD    
---------------------------------------------
greet_s    | Sup!?!??        | SUPELEVEN     
---------------------------------------------
greet_hh   | How swings it?  | HOWDOESITHANG
---------------------------------------------
```

So it's joined to produce v_FieldMaster like this:

1. Any totally different table rows (where comparison is made based on a combination of FieldKey and FieldValue) are included. E.g. Hello, world! only appears in t_Normal, and Sup!?!?? only appears in t_Override.
2. Any rows that match based on Name and Value take the t_Override table's Label field. E.g. How swings it? instead of How's it hangin?
3. Any rows that appear in both (or just t_Override) , but are set as Status=Retired in t_Override, do not appear. E.g. What's shakin'? doesn't appear.

[Quickest way to combine two identical structured tables without duplicate entries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23965352/quickest-way-to-combine-two-identical-structured-tables-without-duplicate-entrie) has got me part of the way there, but I haven't yet figured out how to combine that technique with a where clause matching on t_Override.FieldStatus. Any suggestions very welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a full join, but only select the rows where there is either no override or the override is 'Active'.  Coalesce each field to prioritize the override values if they are there.

```
SELECT 
  COALESCE(o.FieldKey   ,n.FieldKey   ) AS FieldKey   ,
  COALESCE(o.FieldLabel ,n.FieldLabel ) AS FieldLabel ,
  COALESCE(o.FieldStatus,n.FieldStatus) AS FieldStatus
FROM t_Normal n
FULL JOIN t_Override o ON (o.FieldKey = n.FieldKey)
WHERE (o.FieldKey IS NULL OR o.FieldStatus = 'Active')
```

Comment: This looks awesome, but doesn't seem to quite work yet :) If the t_Normal table is empty, will the contents of t_Override still populate the view? Like the Sup!?!?? value in the example.

Comment: Actually what I'm finding is if I remove the WHERE clause then I get results back. I'm setting it to WHERE o.FieldStatus != 'Retired' and that breaks it, even though nothing is set with that status value yet.

Comment: I've realised what my problem is - I'm an idiot. I forgot to mention a key bit of info, which is that the FieldKey can be repeated (this is for populating dropdowns). Given that, the WHERE clause works perfectly. The only thing left is that if I invert the Status check to be o.FieldKey IS NULL AND o.Status IS NULL OR o.Status != 'Retired', it doesn't work. Any idea why?

Comment: Because I'm inverting something that makes the query not makes sense, I know, but is it possible to express that logic as a negative somehow?